# Ssd not seen on boot

Tags: ssd, bios

I hate it when the answer is probably really easy. But, I have this HP probook 6560b. Went to install an ssd into the drive bay but the bios will not recognise it. I then booted into linux via a usb and it was recognised. Installed manjaro onto the ssd, rebooted it and i can seem to get it to be recognised by bios again. The ssd is good as i can put it back in my desktop and it will show straight up again. Has anyone got an idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the BIOS is not recognising it as opposed to UEFI? Have you flashed the latest BIOS firmware?

Comment: I did a disk check in the hp bios and it says disk check failed no disk available